# What is existence?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mind, existence

If I wanted to define "existence" as "that which we encounter but cannot will", what philosophical tradition would that put me in? What authors took up that position or a similar one? What authors criticized that position? Or is this position nonsensical?

To give more details about what that formula could mean, what we "encounter" would be what our mind becomes aware of. For example, I am aware of this table in front of me. Of course, I could become aware of some things, e.g. an "atom", only indirectly, but that may not be an obstacle here. What we "cannot will" would be what our mind was given but is not an immediate product of our mind. That table was not just imagined by my mind. I can get confirmation that it is not just inside my head from others (sane, not blind...) who also can see and touch it. Also, I cannot just will that table into existence with an injunction such as "let there be a table!". Although, of course, I can formulate a plan, get some wood and a saw and get to work to produce a table. But my mind cannot immediately "will" that table into a concrete existence.

I am sure this position is fraught with many issues. I am looking for references that would discuss something close to it.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142643/discussion-on-question-by-frank-what-is-existence); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

Sticking me poor neck out, here's the *etymology* for "exist": From *ex* meaning *out of* and *sistere* for *stand*. Existence then means *independent* of the mind, to *stand outside (the mind*). I suppose at the time the word was coined, people were already convinced that *dreams* aren't real and were in the know in re *hallucinations*. That is this position on existence, so clearly and so elegantly described as *that which we encounter but cannot will*, is *naïve realism* (*contra* idealism).

Comment: Thanks for bringing in the word origin, it is always one of the first things I want clarity about. Might as well start off understanding the word how it was meant to be known!

Comment: It is probably naive realism. There are serious issues with it and many questions that arise from it.

Comment: Even that seemingly naive formula is repleted with details, some of which were pointed out in comments here: for example, we "encounter" things in our head all the time that we do not seem to "will", so that the formula would confer "existence" to possibly non-material things. Another issue, is that what I think I am "encountering" could be in fact "generated" by my mind, although I am not aware of the generation process.

Comment: @Frank, good critique. *Definition* is where all the action takes place in philosophy.

Answer (score 3):

*If I wanted to define "existence" as "that which we encounter but cannot will", what philosophical tradition would that put me in? ... For example, I am aware of this table in front of me. ... not just imagined by my mind.*

Puts me in mind of this:

> What does “matter” mean? Does it mean just “raw material”? No,
> Aristotle characterizes [ὕλη](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BD%95%CE%BB%CE%B7) as
> τὸ δυνάμει.
> [∆ύναμις](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%B4%CF%8D%CE%BD%CE%B1%CE%BC%CE%B9%CF%82#Ancient_Greek) means
> the capacity, or better, the appropriateness for.... The wood present
> in the workshop [281] is in a state of appropriateness for a “table.”
> But it is not just *any* wood that has the character of
> appropriateness for a table; rather, only *this* wood, selected and
> cut to order. But the selection and the cut, i.e., the very character
> of appropriateness, is decided in terms of the “production” of “what
> is to be produced.” But “to produce” means, both in Greek and in the
> original sense of the German *Herstellen*, to *place* something, as
> finished and as looking thus and so, *forth*, into presencing.
>
> [285] ... The orderable wood in the workshop changes into a table.
> What sort of being does this change have? The thing that changes is
> the wood lying present here, not just any wood but *this* wood that is
> appropriate. But “appropriate for” means: tailored to the appearance
> of a table, hence for that wherein the generating of the table — the
> movement — comes to its *end*. The change of the appropriate wood into
> a table consists in the fact that the very appropriateness of what is
> appropriate emerges more fully into view and reaches its fulfillment
> in the appearance of a table and thus comes to stand in the table that
> has been pro-duced, placed *forth*, i.e., into the unhidden. In the
> rest that goes with this standing (of what has attained its stand),
> the emerging appropriateness (δύναμις) of the appropriate (δυνάμει)
> gathers itself up and “has” itself
> ([ἔχει](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%94%CF%87%CE%B5%CE%B9)) as in its end
> ([τέλος](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%84%CE%AD%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82)).
>
> [286] ... But therefore having-itself-within-its-end
> ([ἐντελέχεια](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%90%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B5%CE%BB%CE%AD%CF%87%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%B1)) is the
> essence of movedness (that is, **it is *the being* of a moving
> being**), because this rest most perfectly fulfills what
> [οὐσία](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BF%E1%BD%90%CF%83%CE%AF%CE%B1) is: the intrinsically
> stable presencing in the appearance.

Heidegger GA9 [On the Essence & Concept of φύσις in Aristotle's Physics](https://web.archive.org/web/20170611105750/https://religiousstudies.stanford.edu/wp-content/uploads/1940-PHYSIS.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for this contribution. I'm wondering if I could map "intrinsically stable" to "not willed" - things that we can will seem contingent, we can often if not always imagine a thing and its opposite, whereas what exists has some "stability" or is not subject to any capricious "willing".

Comment: I'm not sure of will as capricious wishing so I'd forbear to say much there.

Comment: Clearly this is redefining "will" for this purpose. It may not match any existing prior definition of "will".

Comment: Yes, I'm more concerned about the effectualness of wishing and imagining things into existence.  Korean buddhism speaks of [the illusory skyflowers](https://books.google.gg/books?id=xROTQHH4RQwC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q=skyflowers&f=false).

Comment: On the other hand, [Kary Mullis](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/science/article/the-eccentric-scientist-behind-the-gold-standard-covid-19-pcr-test) imagined PCR into existence. A eureka! moment worthy of abracadabra!

Comment: That's what this formula is trying to get at: you can't just imagine or will into existence anything material, in the sense that no idea in your head immediately can become material, as in "let there be light".

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help you with references, but I suspect you will have to tighten up your definition of encounter, because it can mean to meet with abstract things, like encountering a problem. I also think that you might have to stretch the meaning of encounter in other ways, too- for example, consider the Earth's core; most people would agree that it exists, but we don't really encounter it in the usual sense of the word.

Comment: Yes, this is a very rough idea at this point. And yes, it is probably fraught with many difficulties. Indeed, "encounter" could be quite indirect: we "encounter" atoms via indirect evidence for example (similar to the Earth's core). But the second part of the formula is effective: we don't "will" the indirect evidence we observe?

Comment: Maybe I'm trying to triage what we become aware of between what we can conjure up as an internal movement of our mind, and what we cannot "conjure up".